# Combining conditions in if clause in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to do this in bash:

```
   //C pseudo code
   if(cond1 is true and (cond2 is true or cond3 is true))
       do something
```

This is what is have

```
var1=abc
var2=
if echo "$var1" | grep -q 'abc' && ( echo "$var2" | grep 'def' || [ "x$var2" = "x" ] ) 
then
 echo hello
fi
```

This still prints hello.

I really need to use the echo grep construct. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It correctly prints `hello` because `[ "x$var2" = "x" ]` is true when `var2` is the empty string.

Comment: (You might want to add `-q` to the second `grep`, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have Bash 3.x you can simplify your code with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=abc
var2=

if [[ $var1 =~ abc && ( $var2 =~ def || -z $var2 ) ]]; then
  echo hello
fi
```

Comment: @abc then why did you tag this as `bash`?